# get all namespaces in scope with XML::LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I need to get all of the namespaces in the scope of an [XML::LibXML::Node](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aNode). The module has a `getNamespaces()` method, but the documentation explicitly says that it

> will not return all namespaces that are in scope, but only the ones declared explicitly for that node.

So how do I get all of the namespaces in the scope of a particular node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find any functions to do this, but it is certainly possible with XPath:

```
@nodes = $node->findnodes('namespace::*');
```

That returns all of the namespaces in a scope visible to `$node`. You can then get prefixes and URIs from the returned XML::LibXML::Node::Namespace objects returned:

```
@prefix_uris = map {[ $_->getLocalName, $_->getData]} @nodes;
```